# Chrome devtools tab reopens the wrong source files after a refresh

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I use chrome to debug my angular project, I open files in the chrome sources by clicking Ctrl+P/O and entering part of the name. Problem is: when I reload, seems chrome keeps all the wrong files open... so if I debugged into another file (didn't close it! just lost focus) and then reload (like, after sources changed and compiled) chrome will close that file, and might even not remember it in the open recents dropdown... *It's like someone sorted in reverse* for some reason...

Is there a way to fix the wrong sorting order through settings or configuration somehow?

Am I the only one finding this not very smart/useful? Considering debugging in browser is a pain in the arse as it is, and unfortunately is the only/go-to option for debugging browser apps...

Comment: It's a bug in devtools.

Comment: couldn't find the bug reported... so I opened one myself: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1376375